# C++: is it a bad method to change the index of a for loop while it's running?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, indexing

I have a for loop that searches an array of structures in order to find a specific structure.
Now this array may be of size 10000.

Inside the for loop I might gather some extra information that will tell me where exactly is the structure you are looking for. So if your index is currently '5', you might find out that it's not in '5' but in '9000'.

So I use this information in order to change the index.

Now the code works perfectly fine without changing the index in the sense that it does find the information needed. However if I'm 100% sure that what I'm doing is correct in this case, is it OK to change the index in the for loop in order to get results faster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just transform your loop into a `while` loop to gain 100% confidence.

Comment: The variables can be modified if you desire it but it can lead to complications if not thought through carefully and implemented correctly. Make absolutely certain that is is really what you want to do.

Comment: I'd use `while` loop, as @ulidtko suggests :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's absolutely fine.  The language doesn't distinguish between changing the index in the loop body and changing it in the increment statement within the loop header.

```
for (initializer-statement; condition-statement; increment-statement)
    loop-body;
```

is *mostly* equivalent to

```
{
    initializer-statement;
    while (condition-statement) {
        loop-body;
        increment-statement;
    }
}
```

One difference is that a `continue` statement within the loop body of a `for` loop will still execute the `increment-statement`, which could cause problems if you're not expecting it.

Also be careful that you don't create an infinite loop by overrunning your terminating condition.

Comment: Not entirely. Be careful about `continue` in `loop-body`.

Comment: Just for fun, I wrote an implementation were break and continue do work :) http://ideone.com/gNoaD It's not perfect either because variable names could collide.

Answer (score 3):

Well, usually, no (I don't mean that it's restricted in some way, you totally *can* do it), just for the means of understanding your own program logic. It can lead to many errors. If you decrease the index in the loop, you may end up with an infinite loop.

If you increase it, you can occasionally make the index too big. For example, if you are accessing array elements, you may try to access an out-of-bonds element like this, and so on and so forth.

*If* you want to modify the index inside the loop, you should *always* understand what you are doing, and probably add some additional condition checks inside the loop itself to avoid strange behavior.

If in your case it works fine, well, then there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I disagree. You have to take some precautions, sure, but not more than in a normal `for` loop header.

Comment: @Gorpik, true, but for a C++ learner, that may be the cause of a lot of bugs, so I wanted to point out that everything must be checked properly. I've seen it a lot of times when people were getting bugs just because they modified the index inside the `for`, and then forgot about it :P

Comment: Another issue is that the moment you see a for loop, you start assuming things that are not true with such shenanigans in the body.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly ok to change the index, as long as it does not overcomplicate the code.

In fact, you might want to separate location "hints" from the actual data, this may give you a simpler way to handle both.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly fine. You **must** add such changes if there is any performance gain for the application (provided, change don't hamper your functionality).